# vba vlookup does not work in loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, macros, vlookup

I am working on a tool to analyse data. The data to be analyzed is manually copied into the first sheet, then I am planning to run a macro which analyzes the data into the second sheet. I need the vlookup function for one property of each entry:

`Worksheets("x1").Cells(z, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Worksheets("x1").Cells(z, 2).Value, Worksheets("x2").Range("$A$1:$B$23"), 2, False)`

Obviously z is the the variable that indicates the current row (I do copy about 700 rows of data in a "for"-loop).

Whenever I try to execute the whole sub it returns a runtime error(1004). The strange thing about it is that whenever I use single steps to execute the macro it works perfectly fine.

Does anybody know whats goin on here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the `$` symbols from the `Range` so it reads: `Worksheets("x1").Cells(z, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Worksheets("x1").Cells(z, 2).Value, Worksheets("x2").Range("A1:B23"), 2, False)`

Comment: This does not solve the problem.

Comment: Did you single step through the entire 700 rows of data? Try writing an error handler (on error goto) and see which row it fails on.

Comment: I solved the problem. The runtime error was caused by a sloppy formula that picks a value from the vlookup-column. Thats probably the reason the code worked without the vlookup. Thank you for introducing me to the concept of error handling though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some sample error handling code to get you going.

```
Sub TestVLookup()

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    For Z = 1 To 700
        Worksheets("x1").Cells(Z, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Worksheets("x1").Cells(Z, 2).Value, Worksheets("x2").Range("$A$1:$B$23"), 2, False)
    Next Z

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print "Z: " + CStr(Z) + "|" + CStr(Err.Number) + ": " + Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: I solved the problem. The runtime error was caused by a sloppy formula in  a different part of the sheet that picks a value from the vlookup-column. Thats probably the reason the code worked without the vlookup. Thank you for introducing me to the concept of error handling though.

Comment: @Maverick13 If you don't know about error handling you should also take a look at view -> immediate window / local  and setting debug points :)